# How to find memory allocated by a kernel level process in linux?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, linux-kernel

I have written a simple kernel module to remove all the vowels from a given string. I want to find out about how much memory is allocated by the process, number of page swaps and number of context switching. But for some reason, `sudo pmap pid` doesn't return anything.

Is there any other command like pmap for kernel level process?

this is the c code(t2.c):

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

MODULE_AUTHOR("K Jivitesh Narayan");

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A program to remove all the vowels from a string");

int init_module(void)
{
    char str[20];
    int len, i, j;
    len=strlen(str);
    strcpy(str,"Hello World");
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(str[i]=='a' || str[i]=='e' || str[i]=='o' || str[i]=='i' || str[i]=='u')
        {
            for(j=i; j<len; j++)
            {
                str[j]=str[j+1];
            }
            len--;
        }

    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "After deleting the vowels, the string will be : %s",str);
    printk(KERN_INFO "The process is \"%s\" (pid %i)\n",
        current->comm, current->pid);

    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "The program is removed \n"); 
}
```

my Makefile is:

```
obj-m += t2.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

after `make` , `sudo insmod t2.ko` and `dmesg`, i get the output(last 2 lines):

```
[ 1108.915141] After deleting the vowels, the string will be : Hll Wrld
[ 1108.915144] The process is "insmod" (pid 3299)
```

the output for `sudo pmap 3299` is nothing. there is no errors.

**edit:
this is the code after adding the jiffies module

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

MODULE_AUTHOR("K Jivitesh Narayan");

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A program to remove all the vowels from a string");

int init_module(void)
{
    unsigned long j1 = jiffies + 3 * HZ;
    char str[20];
    int len, i, j;
    len=strlen(str);
    strcpy(str,"Hello World");
    printk(KERN_INFO "The process is \"%s\" (pid %i)\n", current->comm, current->pid);
    while(jiffies < j1);
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(str[i]=='a' || str[i]=='e' || str[i]=='o' || str[i]=='i' || str[i]=='u')
        {
            for(j=i; j<len; j++)
            {
                str[j]=str[j+1];
            }
            len--;
        }

    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "After deleting the vowels, the string will be : %s",str);

    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "The program is removed \n"); 
}
```

Comment: *"number of context switching"* - what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Have you c [thread]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693454/measure-memory-usage-of-a-certain-linux-driver-module

Comment: maybe this work for you [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693454/measure-memory-usage-of-a-certain-linux-driver-module)

Comment: @red0ct it is the number of context switches a process makes. For a user space process, we can find this out at /proc/[pid]/status.

Comment: @TommasoMerciai thanks for the references. need some time to read it. will get back to you to let you know if it worked.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? As soon as you see the message the process is already dead and PID 3299 likely does not exist anymore.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yes you are right so i used jiffies from linux/jiffies.h header, to keep the process in busy wait while i perform ```sudo pmap``` . but when i do  ``` sudo insmod t2.ko``` , the terminal just hangs.

Comment: @TommasoMerciai i am not sure how to use kmem or ftrace.

Comment: @jiviteshnarayan Well.. of course it does. If you do insmod and your module hangs in its init function, the insmod command will never finish. Open another terminal and do pmap there.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli i guess you are right. but i don't understand what you mean by "open another terminal and do pmap there". if the module itself hangs how can i perform pmap without the pid? . i need to perform insmod without the module hanging.

Comment: @jiviteshnarayan open a new terminal, look for the pid (for example `pidof insmod` or `ps aux | grep insmod`), and *then* use it.